# objective c to swift blocks

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

I'm having trouble converting this objective C to swift blocks
you can see here [Code on Github](https://github.com/evilBird/HBVLinkedTextView/blob/master/HBVLinkedTextViewExample/HBVLinkedTextViewExample/ViewController.m), but i don't have any background in objective C, so i don't really understand this block, here is the code

```
- (LinkedStringTapHandler)exampleHandlerWithTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    LinkedStringTapHandler exampleHandler = ^(NSString *linkedString) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title
                                                       message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Handle tap in linked string '%@'",linkedString]
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    };

    return exampleHandler;
}
```

you can see this code on github https://github.com/evilBird/HBVLinkedTextView/blob/master/HBVLinkedTextViewExample/HBVLinkedTextViewExample/ViewController.m , take a look at that code, Im trying to use it in swift using bridging header. Everything i converted but this line i dont understand.

```
LinkedStringTapHandler exampleHandler = ^(NSString *linkedString)
```

this is what i have done so far

```
func exampleHandlerWithTitler(title:NSString)->LinkedStringTapHandler {

          exampleHandler: LinkedStringTapHandler = (linkedString:NSString) -> () {
                 // alert view code here
            }

return exampleHandler (ERROR here Use of unresolved identifier exampleHandler)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where Objective-C has blocks, Swift has functions. So it's just a matter of knowing how to read Objective-C block syntax - not easy, I know:

```
^(NSString *linkedString)
```

That means: "This is a block taking an NSString parameter (and returning nothing)." So you want to supply here a Swift function that takes an NSString parameter (and returns nothing).

In other words, the definition of LinkedStringTapHandler is equivalent to saying this in Swift:

```
typealias LinkedStringTapHandler = (linkedString:NSString) -> ()
```

So in your code you would form a function of that type and return it:

```
func f(linkedString:NSString) -> () {
    // do stuff
}
return f
```

You could do the same thing with an anonymous function but that's neither here nor there, really.

Comment: well i tried few methods still not really able to convert it

Comment: I've told you all there is to know based on the limited information in the question you asked. I don't actually know what _your_ code is trying to do, do I? You have concealed that. So I've given you the tools to figure it out.

Comment: I'm using this https://github.com/evilBird/HBVLinkedTextView/blob/master/HBVLinkedTextViewExample/HBVLinkedTextViewExample/ViewController.m to find hashtag words but that code is in objC so i am converting it to swift, i did everything else except this func i asked above. I'm sorry im a newbie in swift that why i couldn't figure out by myself.

Comment: @user528432 That's cool but edit your question to show what you're doing. No one can help you with your code if they can't see it. We are helpful but not mind-readers.

Comment: i have added the link in the question

Comment: That is Objective-C code. I'm asking you to paste into your question the actual Swift code that you're trying to write.

Comment: added the code using your answer, but its not really  working

Comment: getting an error when returning exampleHandler  ** Use of unresolved identifier exampleHandler**

Comment: Because you didn't say `let` or `var`. As far as Swift is concerned, that line is nonsense.

Comment: Do you know _any_ Swift at all? It really seems like you don't. I've written a whole new tutorial that might help you; perhaps you should stop and read it before you go any further: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69587/discussion-between-user528432-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

finally this is working

```
func exampleHandlerWithTitler(title:NSString)->LinkedStringTapHandler {

        let  exampleHandler: LinkedStringTapHandler = {(linkedString:String) in {
                 // alert view code here
            }

return exampleHandler 
}
```